# How to get data from attribute in xml file Flutter xml library

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

this is a one of many line from my xml document, and i need to get data from 'requirement' attribute, how i can do this?

```
<ChekList id="001440142173280" requirement="SOME DATA THERE"/>
```

and this is code that i got now

```
Future<String> getXmlData() async{
var document =  XmlDocument.parse(await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/widow.xml'));
document.toXmlString();
var data = document.findAllElements('ChekList');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `getAttribute` gives you attribute values, i.e.

```dart
var data = document.findAllElements('ChekList')
  .map((chekListElement) => chekListElement.getAttribute('requirement'));
```

For other accessors (and extension methods) have a look at the [element class documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/xml/latest/xml/XmlElement-class.html).